# Golang segment stdin stream to file

Tags: go, stdin

instead of writing a pipe to a huge file i want to segment the stream in chunks on signal USR1. i think i got the basics working but the app just hangs and nothing happens, any clues or best practices when handling with an uncontrollable input stream and byte perfect segmentation?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

var done bool

func handle(c chan os.Signal) {
    for {
        sig := <-c
        switch sig {
        case syscall.SIGUSR1:
            fmt.Println("###Sink temporarily_closed###")
            done = true
        case syscall.SIGUSR2:
            fmt.Println("###Sink closed###")
            done = true
        case syscall.SIGHUP:
            fmt.Println("###Sink running###")
        }
        
    }
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}



func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGUSR1, syscall.SIGUSR2, syscall.SIGHUP)
    go handle(c)
    
    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin,1024*10)

    for true {
        if done {
            file, err := os.Create("./temp.file")
            check(err)
            writer := bufio.NewWriter(file)
            written, err := io.Copy(writer,reader)
            check(err)
            fmt.Println(written)
            writer.Flush()
            file.Close()
            reader.Reset(os.Stdin)
            done = false
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no guarantee that `done` will be true because done is set and read on different CPUs. `done` should be atomic or locked by mutex or should receive a value from channel. So you can create separate channel to signal from handler to main loop to do a rotation.

Comment: `file` is open for writing so you should check file.Close() for errors. It call system call `close()` internally and it can fail for multiple reasons.

Comment: hmm i had no problem with the done so far, but i think the reader blocks somehow. i changed the io.copy to written, err := io.CopyN(writer,reader,int64(reader.Buffered())) to make sure it does not block. but no difference. if you are right, could you show me how it is done correctly?

Comment: When i test with cat /dev/urandom | app and send a USR1 signal to the pid of app the signal is trapped and the loop runs, but the io.copyn always returns 0 bytes copied.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to `io.CopyN(dst, src, 4096)` in the loop and rotate the file once in a while. See example. I made rotation by size but it is easy to add signal handling.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

var count int
var f *os.File

func rotate() *os.File {
    if f != nil {
        if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    fname := fmt.Sprintf("./dump-%d.bin", count)
    count++
    f, err := os.Create(fname)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("rotated:", fname)

    return f
}

func main() {
    var n, written int
    reader := os.Stdin

    for {
        if written == 0 || written >= 4096*10 {
            f = rotate()
            written = 0
        }

        n, err := io.CopyN(f, reader, 4096)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        written += n
        log.Println("written:", written)
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example, nice trick with the filehandle i have to remember this, unfortunately i had to typeconvert written += n to written += int(n) to make it work. But if i use it with the application that emmits the pipe stream, the app crashes with broken pipe. i tried to use reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin,1024*10) instead of reader := os.Stdin but also no success.

Comment: I tried with `cat /dev/urandom | ./app` and it works (on osx). What command did you run and what OS?